# Differentiating between data card and pen drive or USB flash drive

Tags: windows, winapi, usb, usb-drive

I am having a Vodaphone data card which can be inserted in a USB port.

I have XP and Vista OS, and I am using `WM_DEVICECHANGE` event of Windows, to know USB Insertion and removal, and it's working fine for me.

But I am not able to differentiate between Data card insertion and Pen drive insertion. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The "pen drive" and "data card" implement different interfaces. You will have subscribed using RegisterDeviceNotification for `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE`. The LPARAM of the `WM_DEVICECHANGE` you get back will then be a `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE*`. This structure has a `dbcc_classguid` member. This will be `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME` for your pen drive, and something else for your datacard - experiment.