# How to write a simple C program for usb port?

Tags: c, usb

i want to test the usb on linux

Comment: What do you want to do? What device do you want to communicate with?

Comment: Please edit your question; adding the following points may get you better answers: 1. What exactly are you trying to accomplish and why (no, it's *not* clear from the question)? 2. What have you tried so far? 3. What results did you get? 4. How did that differ from the results you were expecting?

Comment: A keyboard can be USB.  Make a console program, in C, that accepts one line of textual input.  That's "a c program for USB".  This is an example of why the question you asked won't get the results you intended.

Comment: i love it how the OP `edited` the question (after all these comments), yet still doesnt expand on it, just removed a sentence. No use guys. +1 vote to close.

Comment: It is an ugly question, but it is very clear: I plug in a USB memory stick, find out how much free space there is on it, check file contents on it. That's it.  If I could edit I would re-write it to that.

Answer (score 6):

To detect from C that a new storage device, like a USB pen drive, is inserted,
use [GetLogicalDrives();](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364972%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [GetLogicalDriveStrings()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364975%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and see if any new entries are detected.

Also have a look at how [GetDriveInfo2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/getdriveinfo2/files/) is implemented (it uses WINAPI) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077968/differentiating-between-data-card-and-pen-drive-or-usb-flash-drive) Stack Overflow question, which is related or possibly a dupe.

Once you have the logical drive name, you open it as a directory and enumerate the files there as you would any directory with [FindFirstFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: `GetLogicalDrives()` and `GetLogicalDriveStrings()` aren't part of C.

Answer (score 3):

This will be highly OS-dependent and it will also depend on what kind of USB device you actually want to talk to. Normally you would not access the USB driver directly but would use it via a higher level API. E.g. for a USB disk drive you would just access it like any other disk drive via file system APIs and would not concern yourself with USB APIs.

USB is a complex protocol stack and is designed to hook into the host OS at various points, so you don't normally need to access USB APIs unless you are writing a driver or need to communicate with some kind of non-standard device.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write the low level by yourself, see this John Hyde's book as a reference: [USB Design By Example](http://www.usb-by-example.com/)